# Помогите пожалуйста определить, чем являются в предложениях выделенные места:

Tags: синтаксис

1) Затем они договорятся о помолвке, в зависимости от того, **как все это примет отец**.

2) Едва он увидел выражение лица Элены, **как тотчас же ожили в памяти воспоминания**. (придаточное времени?)

3) Они решили пожениться, **неважно где и неважно как**, но сразу же, как только снова встретятся. (обстоятельство места и меры?)

4) Он полагал, что она знает толк в любви, поскольку прояснила массу мучивших его вопросов, **при том что он не открывал ей своей тайны**.

5) Они не могли обменяться словами, даже самыми незначительными, **даже очень коротко**.

6) Вдобавок к доходам от продажи, **что ей вполне хватало на существование**, она сумела приумножить накопления.

Answer (score 3):

1) Затем они договорятся о помолвке, в зависимости от того, **как все это примет отец**. Придаточное приместоименное  изъяснительное, местоименный коррелят обязателен, местоименная пара: от того, как (союзное слово).

3) Они решили пожениться, **неважно где(1) и неважно как** (2), но (3) сразу же, как только снова встретятся. Обособленный ряд из трех обстоятельств, к третьему обстоятельству относится придаточное времени. Обстоятельства разные (места, образа действия, времени), но оформлены как однородные, с использованием сочинительных союзов.

4) Он полагал, что она знает толк в любви, поскольку прояснила массу мучивших его вопросов, **притом что он не открывал ей своей тайны**. Придаточное уступительное (притом что = хотя).

5) Они не могли обменяться словами, даже самыми незначительными, **даже очень коротко.** Обособленное обстоятельство образа действия.

6) Вдобавок к доходам от продажи, **что ей вполне хватало на существование,** она сумела приумножить накопления. Придаточное определительное (что = которых).

Answer (score 3):

1) Затем они договорятся о помолвке, в зависимости от того(чего именно? какого того?), **как все это примет отец.**-местоимённо-определительное придаточное предложение

2) Едва он увидел выражение лица Элены, **как тотчас же ожили в памяти воспоминания.** главное для придаточного времени (едва...)

3) Они решили пожениться, **неважно где и неважно как**, но сразу же, как только снова встретятся. присоединительная конструкция(присоединяется обстоятельство)

4) Он полагал, что она знает толк в любви, поскольку прояснила массу мучивших его вопросов, **при том что он не открывал ей своей тайны**.-придаточное уступительное

5) Они не могли обменяться словами, даже самыми незначительными, **даже очень коротко.**-присоединительное обстоятельство, связанное с остальной частью предложения частицей даже.

6) Вдобавок к доходам от продажи, **что ей вполне хватало на существование**, она сумела приумножить накопления.-присоединительное придаточное предложение."что"= "чего" можно заменить на "этого".